# What is the implication of the phrase "Would you like a gum"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Back when I lived in United States, I used the following phrase a few times(with different audience)

> Would you like some(food-item)?

> Would you like a chewing-gum?

Every time I used the above phrase, Something unusual happened. For e.g. One time I got the response --Nice packing.

Can somebody explain to me, is there anything wrong with this phrase?

Comment: If you said "would you like a gum", they may have mis-heard "gum" as "gun". In the US "packing" can refer to carrying a gun.

Comment: Chewing gum (like many foods) is generally uncountable.  Usually it would be "some chewing gum", or "some gum", but  "a gum" is not idiomatic.  You can use "a piece of chewing gum" if you are referring to a single piece.

Comment: It might bave been "Nice! [You're] packing!" But that's a lot of assumptions.

Comment: @Peter I don't think he misheard me. I literally had wrigley's in my hand, when I said it.

Answer (score 1):

"Gum" is not countable. You do not say "a gum", you say, "some gum" or just "gum", or you could say "a piece of gum" or "a stick of gum".

"Nice packing" doesn't make sense to me as a response to this question. Perhaps the other person misheard or misunderstood your statement.

Peter notes that they may have misheard and thought you said, "Would you like a gun?", and that "packing" is a slang term in the US for carrying a gun. But it still doesn't make sense. Why would he say "NICE packing"? And in most contexts the question would be very strange. Why would you walk up to someone and offer to give them a gun? Unless you are on a shooting range, or in a gun store, or are being attacked by an enemy army. If I was in a normal situation, at work or some such, and a coworker walked up to me and out of the blue asked what I heard as, "Would you like a gun?", I would surely ask him what he was talking about or why he would ask such a question.

Perhaps you misheard the response. The closest I can get to a perceived dialog here that makes sense is, Person 1: "Would you like a gun?" Person 2: "No thanks, I'm already packing."

Comment: I don't think he misheard me. I literally had wrigley's in my hand, when I said it.

Comment: @max Well, as I said, "nice packing" just makes no sense as a response. Perhaps you misheard him. Otherwise ... I'm baffled.